# Removing Generated Angular DOM attribute tags

Tags: angular

I'm new to angular (angular 4) and I'm testing my test/practice websites on production.

I'm used to see _ng-host-c1 _ngcontent-c1 ng-version tags they are all over the place . I've researched a bit and some tags are related to styling but I searched for websites on production that use angular and they're minimal to none. Can I remove these angular generated attributes if they're not necessary?

Well my question's motivation is if I can remove these tags _ng-host-c1 _ngcontent-c1. Thanks!

Comment: This happens due to emulated view encapsulation. See more here https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation

Comment: I assume you are using the Angular CLI, which creates components with styleUrls. If you are not using those components styles, you can remove them and the extra attributes will be gone.

Answer (score 2):

To remove this, use:

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

In the component decorator function. However, this will remove the encapsulation of your css components. In other words, your css will not be independent and it can be affected by other styles.

Comment: This doesn't remove the attributes comments like:
<!----><!----><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--><!----><!---->